# Add values in a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I create a script which return an array :

```
foreach ($ways as $w){ 
     $nd=$w->nd; 
     foreach ($nd as $w2){       
           $nodes_Array[]=(string)$w2->attributes()->ref; 
        } 
        for($ww=0;$ww<count($nodes_Array);$ww++){ 
           $nodes_Array2[$bb]['main'] = $nodes_Array[$ww]; 
           $nodes_Array2[$bb]['conn'] = array_diff($nodes_Array, array($nodes_Array[$ww]));    
           for($cc=0;$cc<count($nodes_Array2[$bb]['conn']);$cc++){ 
              for($gg=0;$gg<count($node_content);$gg++){ 
                 if($node_content[$gg]['id']==$nodes_Array2[$bb]['conn'][$cc]){ 
                  // MAYBE ADD SOME CODE HERE???
                 } 
              } 
           } 
           $bb++; 
        }   
        unset($nodes_Array); 
  }
```

Output Array:

```
[0] => Array 
    ( 
        [main] => 472321514 
        [conn] => Array 
            ( 
                [1] => 599416249 
                [2] => 2352406409 
                [3] => 496968074) 
    ) ...
```

I'm trying to add "sub arrays" using "keys" (id in main key and lat,lon in conn ) and make this array to looks like this

```
[0] => Array 
    ( 
        [main] => 472321514=>Array( 
             [id]=>..... 
         ) 
        [conn] => Array 
            ( 
                [1] => 599416249=>Array( 
             [lat]=>..... 
             [lon]=>....) 
                [2] => 2352406409=>Array( 
             [lat]=>..... 
             [lon]=>....) 
    )
```

Any help??

Comment: that makes no sense… double keys?!?! you have there some design error in your code.

Comment: What should 'lat' and 'lon' contain? What have you tried?

Comment: i'm trying to add some specs for each value. For example in conn->value 1 (599416249) has lat=.... and lon=....

Comment: describe please more specifically the input data and the result you're expecting

Comment: i receive from web service (http://jxapi.openstreetmap.org/xapi/api/0.6/map?bbox=26.549690,39.103338,26.552812,39.104336) some ways with nodes.I'm trying to create an array with all  combinations of node connections.In this array "main" is the main node and all conns values are other nodes which are includes in the way. The problem is i want to add latlon for every node...

Comment: P.S: Sorry for my english!

Comment: @user2850530 then recursion should be enough. Create something like `function addNodes($nodes)` which calls itself to add subnodes

Comment: There is no such thing as double keys. If the numbers are unique, put them as keys of array. And previous keys: main, conn as properties.

Comment: the problem is many numbers are same...